# facebook application : get birthday

Tags: facebook

I would like to know how to get the date of birthday of the user of facebook.
Here is the code which deal with facebook api :

```
<?php require 'src/facebook.php';
define("FB_APP_ID","***");
define("FB_SECRET","***");
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => FB_APP_ID,
  'secret' => FB_SECRET,
  'cookie' => true, 
));
$currentUser = $facebook->getUser();
if($currentUser) {
try
{
    $facebook_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
    $friends_fields = $facebook->api('/me/friends');
}
catch (FacebookApiException $e)
{
    print_r($e);
    $user = null;
}
}


$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(
array(
    'scope' => 'user_birthday, birthday, date_birthday, email, offline_access, publish_stream'
)
);
$logoutUrl  = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
?>
```

I tried $facebook_profile['user_birthday'] and $facebook_profile['birthday']
But it does not work.

I don't know how to do ? Can you help me please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct permission for birthday is `user_birthday`

Verify you have the permission

```
$permissions = $facebook->api('/me/permissions');
$permissions["data"][0]["user_birthday"];
```

Seeing that you have `facebook_profile`, you should just dump the contents of that response to see what you do have.

Also ensure the user *did* set his/her birthday...

Comment: $facebook_profile displays

`Array ( [id] => *** [name] => *** [first_name] => *** [last_name] => ** [link] => http://www.facebook.com/*** [username] => *** [gender] => female [email] => *** [timezone] => 1 [locale] => fr_FR [verified] => 1 [updated_time] => 2012-12-10T16:25:31+0000 )`

It does not refer to user_birthday.
The user do have a birthday . 
"count($permissions["data"][0]);" display 10, when i do a `foreach($permissions["data"][0] as $p) {echo $p;}` I have "1111111111", so i do have the permission

Comment: @user1728824 that does not prove you have permission, it proves you have 10 items of permission. please check `$permissions["data"][0]["user_birthday"] == 1`

Comment: You are right, i do not have the permission, `if ($permissions["data"][0]["user_birthday"] == 1) {
   echo "permission ok";
  } else {
   echo "no permission";
  }` displays "no permission"

Comment: I don't understand, `$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(
array(
    'scope' => 'user_birthday, birthday, date_birthday, email, offline_access, publish_stream'
)
);` should deal with the permission, no ?

Answer (score 0):

There's probably more than one way to do it, but you should be able to get the user's birthday from an FQL call via [the SDK `api()` method](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-api/):

```
$result = $facebook->api(array(
    'method' => 'fql.query',
    'query' => 'SELECT birthday_date FROM user WHERE uid = me()',
));

$birthday = $result[0]['birthday_date'];
```

You'll need to have `user_birthday` or `friends_birthday` permissions to read the `birthday` and `birthday_date` fields.

Comment: How do I get the permissions ?

Comment: When you initially prompt the user to grant access to your app.